# How to get query arguments from RequestURI without losing character

Tags: http, go, fasthttp

I want to get the query arguments from RequestURI in golang.
The URL is like that:
`http://localhost:3000/add-ebay?authToken=AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**6d8JWQ**nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2...`

And my code is followings:

```
func CreateEbayProfile(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

    log.Println( ctx.QueryArgs().Peek("authToken"))
               ....
}
```

The result is that:

```
AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**6d8JWQ**nY sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY sEZ2...
```

But I want to result like that:

```
AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**6d8JWQ**nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2...
```

How can I get the correct result? And why this is happening?

Comment: Spaces in a URL query are escaped as `+`. As far as a query string goes, the values are equivalent.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Comment: Technically you are getting the correct result; if the parameter is supposed to include literal `+` characters, then the input is incorrect, and should be URL-encoded (passing `%2B` in place of `+`).

Comment: thanks Adrian. I solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [strings.Replace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) to replace a character with another one.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**6d8JWQ**nY sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY sEZ2...";
    conv := strings.Replace(s, " ", "+", -1)

    fmt.Println(conv) //AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**6d8JWQ**nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2...

}
```

Here you can find a [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pEvjyiUAfo) reproducing this code.

Comment: I think your answer is not good solution. I have to encode url. This is best solution, I think. Anyway I appreciate your help.AndreaM